# Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL in composer network ping

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

When I ping blockchain business network using composer network ping command getting following error:

Command :

```
ubuntu@pc:~/Yogendra/BlockChain/order-supply-chain-27-Feb-2018/order-supply-chain$ sudo composer network ping -c yogi@order-supply-chain
```

Error :

> E0227 17:19:27.692776546   15301 ssl_transport_security.c:921]
>   Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed. E0227
>   17:19:27.708774523   15301 ssl_transport_security.c:921] Handshake
>   failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed. Error:
>   Error trying invoke business network. Error: Peer has rejected
>   transaction
>   '975aa720ec13a9ca2b58022e44d63cc69a815e802fd5495c904b5d44e9b2d251'
>   with code ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE Command failed

Answer (score 0):

The answer and comments in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46191040/hyperledger-composer-connection-issue-when-using-tls) should help you if you are using Composer v0.16.x

[This tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org) should help with the format of the connection.json file.

If you are using v0.17.x, you will need [this version](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/next/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org) of the tutorial.

**UPDATE:**

Composer v0.19 is now the latest version with many enhancements and some breaking changes.  The tutorial has been updated accordingly and the [revised tutorial is here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org).